# How can i post using Python urllib in html input type submit

Tags: python, post, submit, urllib2, urllib

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit ! " class="submit" accesskey="s">
<body class="tx-content-container" contenteditable="true" style="padding: 8px; width: 700px; margin-left: 115px; margin-right: 114px; height: 384px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><p>dd</p></body>
```

How can i post using urllib module???

I want to post something on some website.

What should i do?